# MS Access: Bind Combo Box to Primary Key but display field from another table

Tags: ms-access, combobox

I have two tables, "Orders" and "Parts" that are related by the "Part_ID" field. I have an Order form with a combobox that I want to bind Part_ID to, but display the "Part" field in "Parts" table instead.

I referred to [this tutorial](https://www.techonthenet.com/access/comboboxes/bind_index.php) which nearly got me to the solution. The problem is that the combobox only displays "Part" fields that already exist in the "Orders" table. This means that if I add a new "Part" to "Parts", it won't show up in the combobox.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/waXf2.jpg) is what my combobox's row source looks like. How can I make the combobox display "Part"s that exist in the "Parts" table instead of the ones that exist in the "Orders" table?

**EDIT:**
Here are the [table structures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lB6kA.jpg) and their relationship.

Comment: Please share the table structure on both relevant tables.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the Orders table from your row source query. That should do it.

The SQL should read something like this:

```
SELECT Part_ID, Part
FROM Parts
```